# Which character has the distinction of being personally identified as the "Mummy" in the most motion pictures?

Tags: movie, character-identification, undead

There are tons of nameless mummies in countless mummy movies, but some mummies are supposed to represent specific individuals. For instance, Imhotep was the main mummy in most of the Brendan Fraser mummy movies. Which character, historic or imagined, has the distinction of being personally identified as a "Mummy" in the most motion pictures?

Comment: Does this mean we have to watch _all_ "mummy" movies to be able to answer this question?

Comment: @Izkata ;) I don't know what kind of voodoo some of you folks conjur up to answer some of these questions. I suspect there's a database outhere somewhere.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It may be down to:

[Imhotep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imhotep), a real Egyptian chancellor/high priest, popularized as a mummy in [Boris Karloff's The Mummy [1932]](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0023245/?ref_=fn_al_tt_10) and the more recent [The Mummy [1999]](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120616/?ref_=fn_al_tt_5) and [The Mummy Returns [2001]](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0209163/)- both with Brendan Fraser, or:

[Kharis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kharis), a fictional character, who was featured by Lon Chaney in [The Mummy's Tomb [1942]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mummy%27s_Tomb), [The Mummy's Ghost [1944]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mummy%27s_Ghost), and [The Mummy's Curse [also 1944]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mummy%27s_Curse); he was also played by Christopher Lee in [The Mummy [1959]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mummy_%281959_film%29).

Comment: +1! I always thought Kharis was much more frightening than Imhotep. It's the difference between CGI trickery and someone you **really** wouldn't want to meet on a dark night!

Comment: Boris Karloff wasn't done with CGI.